# 301 redirecting while preserving path structure

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

I am trying to redirect every URL from my old site to my new site, so that, if someone goes to say oldsite.com/about it redirects to store.newsite.com/about rather than just store.newsite.com/index.php

I tried the following code but for some reason it always takes me to store.newsite.com/index.php when I go to oldsite.com/about instead of taking me to store.newsite.com/about, and the same goes for every other path on the site. Is there something wrong with what I am putting in my .htaccess file?

Thank you!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://store.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Yes. I figured out I had incorrect syntax with backslashes before the period. Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it with this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.site$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.site$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://store.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```